# ¿Cómo hacer un fondo animado?

Tags: html, css

Lo que quiero hacer no sé cómo se dirá pero lo explicaré: es poner dos imágenes una encima de otra cosa que la de atrás esté oculta y la del frente visible. Al pasar el cursor encima de la imagen de frente se oculte y se ponga visible lo que está atrás pero que vaya creciendo con una animación.

Ejemplo:

```css
.Objeto{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: red;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
.Objeto:hover{
    width: 350px; 
    height: 350px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="Objeto"></div>
```

Así como crece el objeto quiero que aparezca el imagen de atrás pero el problema surge cuando se oculta, ya que al ocultarse y mover el cursor la imagen aparece y desaparece hasta dejar el cursor detenido.

Comment: ¿Podrías corregir el CSS? Edita tu pregunta, copia y pega el código y luego basta con seleccionarlo y pulsar en el botón de código que tiene dos llaves (`{}`).

Comment: Ya he corregido yo el tema del formato de código. ¿Podrías explicar con un ejemplo qué es lo que te ocurre cuando trabajas con imágenes? Sin código y sin verlo es más difícil entenderlo y ayudarte a corregirlo.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *creciendo*? ¿Te vale con que se difumine una y aparezca otra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te dejo una alternativa a la de Slavis sin capa intermedia que se parece al ejemplo que has dado, para ello me he basado [en esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393231/css-on-hover-show-and-hide-different-divs-at-the-same-time), pero intercambiando el atributo *`display`* por *`visibility`*.

El motivo es que el segundo permite el uso de transiciones CSS, por lo demás actúa de forma similar a **display:none** en que recargan el layout.

Edición: He añadido un suavizado cuando se realiza el `hover` añadiendo una transición a `Objeto` y `opacity` (opacidad) a cada elemento según su estado inicial, pero son totalmente opcionales y es posible no utilizar estos, simplemente se notará más bruscamente el cambio.

```css
.Objeto{
    position:absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    background: url('https://www.nps.gov/common/uploads/stories/images/nri/20161013/articles/71B2B5D2-1DD8-B71B-0B76C91DF3E21792/71B2B5D2-1DD8-B71B-0B76C91DF3E21792.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.Objeto2{
    position:absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    visibility: hidden;   
    opacity:0;
    background: url("https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/40000/velka/mountain-meet-the-sea.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

 .contenedor:hover .Objeto2{
   visibility : visible;
   opacity:1;
   width: 350px; 
   height: 350px;
 }
 .contenedor:hover .Objeto{
   visibility : hidden;   
   opacity:0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="Objeto"></div>
  <div class="Objeto2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh Muchisimas gracias Yo ponía e hover en la imagen de fondo nunca se me ocurrió ponerlo en el contenedor

Answer (score 3):

Mira lo que he probado en local, a ver si te vale algo así, lo he hecho solo con html y css.

Basicamente para evitar que la foto crezca y desaparezca, he creado una capa transparente que es digamos sobre la que usas la pseudo clase **:hover**

Si quisieras que las fotos sean responsives o no desentonen mucho, usa divs en vez de img con backgrounds-image.

```css
.Objeto{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}

.Objeto > img, .transparent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.hidden {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    transition:  all 400ms linear;
}

.visible {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition:  all 150ms linear;
}

.transparent:hover + .visible{
    opacity: 0;
}

.transparent:hover ~ .hidden  {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.transparent {
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="Objeto">
    <div class = "transparent"></div>
    <img class = "visible" src = "https://www.ranchomagico.com.mx/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/pinguino-emperador4-730x410.jpg"/>
    <img class = "hidden" src = "https://cuantoviven.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/cuanto-viven-los-canguros.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Buen ejemplo, te lo he arreglado para que se pueda ejecutar directamente aquí

Comment: Gracias, ¿como haces para que se pueda ejecutar aquí?

Comment: Cuando creas una respuesta, hay un botón para insertar un fragmento de código HTML + CSS + JS. También puedes usar el atajo de teclado Ctrl + M

Comment: Muchas Gracias Pablo

Comment: Gracias una forma muy interesante de ver me ayuda a expandir mis conocimientos, de nuevo muchas gracias